# How to create a web part to track page creation time

Tags: web-part, development, publishing-site

I am new to SharePoint Server 2007 Web Part, and I am using SharePoint Server 2007 on Windows Server 2008. I program using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5.

I want to create a simple web part which could display page creation time and modified time (display such time information at the bottom of a web page).

Any reference code samples or tutorials -- anything helpful for a newbie of SharePoint 2007 Web Part or this specific time tracking issue is helpful.

Comment: @George2: Have you read any SharePoint developer books or taken any training courses? If you're just getting started this will help you *a lot*. We would really like specific, focussed questions on this site if possible please.

Comment: Alex, any good books or training courses do you recommend?

Comment: @George2: This question should help: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/8/what-resources-would-you-recommend-to-someone-who-would-like-to-learn-and-possibl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/PageFooter.aspx) ?

It is a footer that will display last modified date and username.

Comment: Cool, I will try that solution!

Comment: I read the document. My issue is how to deploy such user control? the document you mentioned seems to cover more about how to develop a user control, but less about how to deploy a user control. Appreciate if you could recommend me a step-by-step guide covers the cycle about develop and deploy a simple user control in MOSS 2007.

Comment: Cool Kasper, question answered!

Answer (score 1):

a little less code: SPContext.Current.Item.File.TimeLastModified.ToString()

obviously you will have to create a web part tha renders the string above. Just google how create a hello world web part.

Or you could use a content editor web part that runs some jQuery that will read Modified property of the current page by making a call to the webservices. I am sure Marc D Anderson can tell you more about how to do this :)

Comment: Jaap, my current issue is how to deploy such user control? I read some document, but they cover more about how to develop a user control, but less about how to deploy a user control. Appreciate if you could recommend me a step-by-step guide covers the cycle about develop and deploy a simple user control in MOSS 2007.

Comment: BTW, could you recommend me a good jQuery book, which is helpful for MOSS 2007 development?